# nfs4 idmapping with sss

Tags: sssd, nfs4

We have a Dell enterprise file server that implements NFS4 ACLs.
I can mount a NFS4 directory and nfs4_setfacl and nfs4_getfacl work correctly. Unfortunately, I am unable to get an ls listing to work correctly.
I've enabled id mapping:

echo 0 > /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping

and configured /etc/idmapd

```
[General]
Verbosity = 10
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if it differs from FQDN minus hostname
Domain = example.com
[Translation]
Method = sss
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
```

*/etc/request-key.d/id_resolver.conf*
is configured

When I do a ls -l on a mounted file, the request-key is using "localhost" instead of "example.com"

*nfsidmap -l*

```
3 .id_resolver keys found:
uid:root@localhost
uid:gweatherby@localhost
gid:wheel@localhost
```

Has anyone figured out how to make this work?

---

Figured it out:

I was using the domain name in the nfs4_setfacl command. e.g.

*nfs4_setfacl -a A::gweatherby@example.com :r filename*

just using the account name works as desired

*nfs4_setfacl -a A::gweatherby :r filename*